python Gymnasium doesn't have an environment
i'm using Gymnasium, and although I just downloaded it(I have python 3.12.5 and I already tried it with 3.13.0) when I run the following lines
env = gym.make("LunarLander-v3", continuous=True)
state, _ = env.reset()

I get this error
VersionNotFound: Environment version `v3` for environment `LunarLander` doesn't exist. 
It provides versioned environments: [ `v2` ]."

which is ironic 'v3' is on the frontpage of gymnasium, so what is happening??

For my environment Ubuntu Linux with Conda this works:
conda install -c conda-forge libffi
More info here: libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris
